# Spring Cloud DataFlow Local-Server 1.2.2 fails to startup on Windows 10

Tags: java, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm attempting to follow the spring cloud data flow tutorial at this link http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#quick-start.

When at Step 2, executing the following line

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar
```

Results in the following exception:

`2017-07-01 16:21:00.218  WARN 3224 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/config/features/TaskConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'taskService' parameter 5; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskLauncher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/local/LocalDeployerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'taskLauncher' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.cloud.deployer.local-org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalDeployerProperties': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalDeployerProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Java executable discovered via 'java.home' system property 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre' is not executable or does not exist.`

I think the key is the 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre' appears to be the wrong path to the java binaries. I would expect this to be the %JRE_HOME%\bin directory.

I wrote a small program to dump the system properties which produced the following:

`java.home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre`

My JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, CLASSPATH and JDK_HOME environment variables are set as following

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
JDK_HOME %JAVA_HOME%
JRE_HOME %JAVA_HOME%\jre
CLASSPATH .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
```

The PATH variable is set to %JAVA_HOME%\bin

I have restarted my command prompt several times.

When I run the following command for the 1.1.4 version, the server starts up without error:

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
```

I have tried to remove the JRE_HOME variable and have CLASSPATH set to .

Update: Adding output of dir c:\java.exe /s /b

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_260505593\java.exe
c:\Users\All Users\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
c:\Users\All Users\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_260505593\java.exe
```

Comment: What is the output of `dir c:\java.exe /s /b` ?

Comment: >c:\java.exe /s /b
'c:\java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You mistyped it. Make sure you run this in a cmd and exactly the way it is written above

Comment: My mistake

>dir c:\java.exe /s /b
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_260505593\java.exe
c:\Users\All Users\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
c:\Users\All Users\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_260505593\java.exe

Comment: Would you mind adding this to your question ? It is nearly unreadable the way it is now. Besides that it might be a good idea to concentrate on either x86 or x64 Java and uninstall the other. And use the short name of the directory Java is installed in (`C:\Progra~1` for example, you find it by using `dir C:\prog* /X`) or install your Java into `C:\dev´. I think to cause of your problems is that Java is not in `jre` but in `jre\bin` so set `JAVA_HOME` accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a bug: (impacts 1.2.2.RELEASE only and is fixed by 1.2.3.RELEASE)**

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/issues/58

**"Work around"** solution is to goto the `JRE` path of java on your system and to run the following command

(note to other users to find your java path type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in command prompt window, if there is a 'jdk' in the java home path make sure to alter it to 'jre' for the 'cd' command below. We need to navigate to the jre dir not jdk we also appended '\bin')

1. Navigate to the JRE's bin directory

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin    `(notice: in the path "jre1.8" not jdk`)

2. Make a copy of 'java.exe' called 'java' in this this same directory

> copy java.exe java

**Summary of Bug/Workaround:**

the bug is basically... the developers were expecting the java executable to be called `java` and not `java.exe` as it is named on Windows OS. So the workaround is to make a copy of java.exe and name it java in that JRE's bin directory...

not sure how something like this makes it to production release though... :/

Comment: Hi, @Selwyn. It was an oversight in not having a CI plan for Windows -
 we now have it. The suggested workaround allows getting you going for the time being. We are very much addressing the problem - please track [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local#59](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/pull/59) PR for the fix progress and release date.

Comment: Workaround still doesn't work for me, but pointing out its a bug and linking to the issue was valuable. Marking as solved.

Comment: @PatrickHuber make sure you perform the workaround in the correct JRE path on your system. The correct one will be which ever jre is pointed to by %JAVA_HOME% environmental variable. The exception in your stack trace should provide you with a hint as to which version is the correct path

Answer (score 1):

This bug is is fixed in the 1.2.3.RELEASE